# XML Feeds extensible parsers: what is Value in Parser or Bundle in Processor?

Tags: feeds

I am trying to generate an apartment listing through Feeds and Extensible Parsers from a feed like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><apartmentFeed version="1.0" timestamp="20150318:16:31:51">
<apartment id="529">
<general>
    <lang>en</lang>
    <reference>000525</reference>
    <name><![CDATA[Pilatos]]>
    </name>
    <general_url><![CDATA[https://www.waytostay.com/seville-apartments/pilatos-0525/?orgid=949&utm_content=feed]]></general_url>
    <reviews_link><![CDATA[https://www.waytostay.com/seville-apartments/pilatos-0525/reviews?orgid=949&utm_content=feed]]></reviews_link>
    <location_link><![CDATA[https://www.waytostay.com/seville-apartments/pilatos-0525/location?orgid=949&utm_content=feed]]></location_link>
    <availability_link><![CDATA[https://www.waytostay.com/seville-apartments/pilatos-0525/availability?orgid=949&utm_content=feed]]></availability_link>
    <updated>2015-02-25 13:56:27</updated>
    <business_suitable>false</business_suitable>
    <number_of_apartments>1</number_of_apartments>
    <cancelation_policy></cancelation_policy>
    <class>Comfort</class>
    <themes>
                </themes>
    <inside_description><![CDATA[modern marble]]></inside_description>
    <outside_description><![CDATA[mudéjar marble]]></outside_description>
    <long_description></long_description>
</general>
<location>
    <country><![CDATA[Spain]]></country>
    <city><![CDATA[Seville]]></city>
    <neighbourhood><![CDATA[Santa Cruz – Catedral]]></neighbourhood>
    <area><![CDATA[Santa Cruz – Catedral]]></area>
    <longitude>-5.988208651542664</longitude>
    <latitude>37.38950140217916</latitude>
</location>
```

After navigating information and videos the whole day, the only thing I think I have clear is that the context should be //apartment (most examples are very simple XML and default Feed importer/page).

I found no information on what to do with "Value" in the settings for XML parser. I tried with empty values or just copying the "Name" or using the the names of the fields in the created destination page called "WtSFeed".
No specific info on "Bundle" either, but I guess it should go to that same destination page.

When I go to that WtSFeed page and introduce the XML address, it creates the node of the import page, but no additional nodes for the apartment pages, although the blue bar indicates it has been downloading.

To keep it simple I limited the import to just the 3 easiest data using -latitude- and -longitude- for newly created "lat" and "lon" text-fields and -reference- for the title field, since I wouldn't even know how to address the -name- that has a -![CDATA ...- in it, nor how to address "id" that is part of -apartment id="xxx"-

Probably too many doubts at the time, but if someone could explain how to at least create the new nodes from those three simple data, I'd have a starting point. Maybe it means a better understanding of "Value" and "Bundles" too.

Thanks

This is under drupal 7.34 with Feeds 7.0-2.0-alpha8 and Extensible parser 7.x-1.0-beta1
(I substituted > and < for - otherwise it disappears)

Comment: Trying to go through it step by step, in reality the first question would be if for the indicated feed, under Select a parser, the "Common syndication parser" would be enough (it says "parse XML feeds") or would it really have to be "XML Xpath parser"?